# How to fix: A failed git push: The file 'app.config' and the file 'App.config' pushed differ in case

Tags: git

I did a `git svn clone` first (the SVN repo is huge!), that resulted in a local git repo (I removed the svn stuff (e.g. .git/svn and .git/config)).

Now I wanted to push it to the Visual Studio Hosted git, and I get this error: 
remote unpack failed: error The tree object 0db6571b0a0437f867b536f4b41810edaaa41f0c was rejected: The file 'app.config' and the file 'App.config' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them.

This is the full dump from the terminal:

```
$ git push -u origin --all
Username for 'https://<private>.visualstudio.com': frank
Password for 'https://frank@<private>.visualstudio.com': 
Counting objects: 395082, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (97018/97018), done.
Writing objects: 100% (395082/395082), 2.29 GiB | 58.26 MiB/s, done.
Total 395082 (delta 279171), reused 395082 (delta 279171)
error: remote unpack failed: error The tree object 0db6571b0a0437f867b536f4b41810edaaa41f0c was rejected: The file 'app.config' and the file 'App.config' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them.
To https://<private>.visualstudio.com/<private>/_git/<private>
 ! [remote rejected]       master -> master (The tree object 0db6571b0a0437f867b536f4b41810edaaa41f0c was rejected: The file 'app.config' and the file 'App.config' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<private>.visualstudio.com/<private>/_git/<private>'
```

I am not sure which App.config it is, and I am also unsure if the [Aa]pp.config's are inside older commits.

The main question is:

- How do I get this repo pushed all together?

The "sub"-questions are:

- How do I find this specific file?
- How do I rename the file in an older commit?
- Can I ignore this file as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this in two ways, the both work independently:

**Method one:**

Install 'git-extras' first.

Then identify the wrong file by inspecting the tree object using:

`git ls-tree -r --long --full-tree 0db6571b0a0437f867b536f4b41810edaaa41f0c`

After that use git obliterate from git extras:

`git obliterate path/to/App.config`

**Method two:**

I was using Azure DevOps' Git as a target. That apparently has some secret settings ;-)
Turning these options off made it all work too:

[image]

Comment: Just to comment that you should not turn off that setting if you don't want the following to happen: in OSs that are not case sensitive, like Windows, two folders with the same name with differences only on the capitalizations will create two different pull requests in the same branch because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always rename one of the files to something different just to get into source control and inspect it, then figure out what to do with them.

They might be the same file, just different casing since it looks like your current system you're working on is based on a case sensitive file system.

There is the git mv [filename] command as well, if you need to specific change the casing of a file for git.

Comment: How do I find this file? I have hundreds of App.configs. I'll look into git mv

Comment: Well, it's gotta be in the same folder as each other, if the files were in different folders, you wouldn't get this message.  So I'd start off by searching for those files names to find out where the duplication is to locate the correct files to look at.

Comment: I'll write a script for this tomorrow. But my gutfeeling says it's in an old commit and not in the current directory.

Comment: I'll be interested to see what comes up.

Comment: The file is in an older commit and not in the current version.